# How do I set the content-type when using python's http server?

Tags: python, content-type, httpserver

I tried using `send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')`. However, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in a class derived from `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`:

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
self.end_headers()
# Your response body follows with self.wfile.write()
```

See more [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) and [here](https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/simple-python-http-server/).

Answer (score -4):

May need double quotes? See [example](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer). I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried double quotes but this does not work as well. What appears to work is "content_type" instead of "Content-Type" (using underscore instead of a hyphen). However, I need this to be a hyphen so some other programs that rely on "Content-Type" will work.

Comment: You might want to look at theactual header in the response: even if youset it as content_type in the API call, it could correctly use the - version in the actual header